# Spring mvc обновление таблицы без обновления страницы

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, crud

Имеется форма-таблица с инпутами, при сабмите данные обновляются в бд и происходит обновление страницы с новыми данными. Как это сделать без обновления страницы ?

Comment: вы используете jsp? или у вас другой шаблонизатор, фреймворк, etc?

Comment: надо использовать ajax

Comment: Да, использую jsp